# Python: Split string conditional on elements in other list

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, conditional-statements

So I have a pandas dataframe that is structured the following way:

```
In: df.head(1)
Out:
Individual      Employer                    EmployerState       BranchesState                    BranchesNr
872570          (4210, 7463, 23130, 133752) (MN, GA, NY, AZ)    (MN, AZ, GA, AZ, NY, AZ, AZ)    (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Now what I intend  to do is to split all the multiple employer information and create a single record for each employer-employee pair, like so:

```
Individual       Employer       EmployerState   BranchesState       BranchesNr
872570           4210           MN              MN, AZ              0, 1
872570           7463           GA              GA, AZ              0, 1
872570           23130          NY              NY, AZ              0, 1
872570           133752         AZ              AZ                  0
```

Currently, I am able to do this for the columns ***Individual, Employer and EmployerState*** by applying the following code:

```
rows = [] # Store individuals in empty array
for _, row in indv_sub.iterrows():

# If there are multiple employers
# Example:
# Individual | Employer      =>         Individual | Employer
# 123        | (XY, AB)                 123        | XY
#                                       123        | AB

    if len(str(row['Employer']).split(','))>1:
        # split the individual record into as many employers as an individual has
        [rows.append(
                 [row['Individual'], 
                  m.replace('(','').replace(')',''),
                  l.replace('(','').replace(')',''),
                  row['BranchesState']]) 
                  for m,l in zip(row['Employer'].split(','),row['EmployerState'].split(','))]
    else:
        # just add the single employer
        rows.append([row['Individual'], row['Employer'], row['EmployerState'], row['BranchesState']])

indv_relevant = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=('Individual','Employer','EmployerState','BranchesState'))
indv_relevant = indv_relevant.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

This works well but I am not quite able to split the BranchesState column. I added a BranchesNr field that indicates with a 0 the branches of the next employer. So consider this example:

```
 Employer           BranchesState                   BranchesNr
 (MN, GA, NY, AZ)   (MN, AZ, GA, AZ, NY, AZ, AZ)    (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

The first to values are 0,1 followed by a 0, which indicates that all the branches up to the second position belong to the first employer.

```
list(row['BranchesState'].split(','))[:2] # would be attributable to the first employer
```

Next is position 3 to 4, which is attributed to the second employer and so on. I am not quite sure how to implement it nicely. Any ideas or suggestions?

P.S: The fields are strings and not tuples / lists as it would seem. Also 0,1,0 is just an example, some sequences are 0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,3,4, etc.

To include more variation of the data, here is an example of 10 observations:

{u'BrnchOfLoc_FirmNr': {1490: u'(0, 0)',
  1498: u'(0, 0, 1, 2)',
  1594: u'(0, 0)',
  1618: u'(0, 0, 0)',
  1632: u'(0, 0)',
  1633: u'(0, 0)',
  1687: u'(0, 0)',
  1738: u'(0, 0)',
  1783: u'(0, 0, 1)',
  1793: u'(0, 0)'},
 u'BrnchOfLoc_state': {1490: u'(CA, CA)',
  1498: u'(CA, CA, CA, CA)',
  1594: u'(PA, PA)',
  1618: u'(CA, CA, CA)',
  1632: u'(NY, NY)',
  1633: u'(NH, NH)',
  1687: u'(FL, FL)',
  1738: u'(CA, CA)',
  1783: u'(MS, MS, LA)',
  1793: u'(NJ, NJ)'},
 u'CrntEmp_orgPK': {1490: u'(13572, 144875)',
  1498: u'(112059, 137743)',
  1594: u'(519, 162200)',
  1618: u'(23131, 111532, 113269)',
  1632: u'(6627, 118660)',
  1633: u'(6413, 131406)',
  1687: u'(131587, 142133)',
  1738: u'(23131, 105698)',
  1783: u'(159778, 160431)',
  1793: u'(6413, 128859)'},
 u'CrntEmp_state': {1490: u'(CA, CA)',
  1498: u'(CA, CA)',
  1594: u'(PA, PA)',
  1618: u'(NY, CA, CA)',
  1632: u'(NY, NY)',
  1633: u'(MA, NH)',
  1687: u'(FL, FL)',
  1738: u'(NY, CA)',
  1783: u'(MS, LA)',
  1793: u'(MA, NJ)'},
 u'Info_indvlPK': {1490: u'731003',
  1498: u'29443',
  1594: u'708024',
  1618: u'707057',
  1632: u'830502',
  1633: u'854101',
  1687: u'706344',
  1738: u'867229',
  1783: u'734227',
  1793: u'849856'},
 'NumberEmployer': {1490: 2,
  1498: 2,
  1594: 2,
  1618: 3,
  1632: 2,
  1633: 2,
  1687: 2,
  1738: 2,
  1783: 2,
  1793: 2}}

Comment: Can you provide a smaller example that shows exactly what output you'd like to receive for a given input?  I'm not totally clear on how the branches should be working, and a complete sample would help.  Also, putting the code for that sample dataframe in would help people answer.

Comment: I made the column names more interpretable and extended the example. Does this help?

Comment: how about `df.head().to_dict('list')`? It would be good to see some more variation in the data.

Comment: Added 10 observations to my post. Hope that helps. And thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you nearly there, but I am still not clear on the rules for splitting `EmployerState`.  Perhaps you can include an additional example?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'BranchesNr': ['(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)', 
                    '(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)'],
     'BranchesState': ['(MN, AZ, GA, AZ, NY, AZ, AZ)',
                       '(MN, AZ, GA, AZ, NY, AZ, AZ)'],
     'Employer': ['(4210, 7463, 23130, 133752)',
                  '(4210, 7463, 23130, 133752)'],
     'EmployerState': ['(MN, GA, NY, AZ)',
                       '(MN, GA, NY, AZ)'],
     'Individual': [872570, 872570]})

df['Employer'] = df.Employer.str.findall('(\d+)')
df['EmployerState'] = df.EmployerState.str.findall('(\w+)')
df['BranchesState'] = df.BranchesState.str.findall('(\w+)')
df['BranchesNr'] = df.BranchesNr.str.findall('(0|1)+')

indices = [[0] + [n for n, flag in enumerate(branches, 1) if flag == '1'] 
           for branches in df.BranchesNr]

>>> [(row. Individual, row.Employer[n], row. EmployerState[n]) 
     for idx, row in df.iterrows() 
     for n in range(len(row.Employer))]


[(872570, '4210', 'MN'),
 (872570, '7463', 'GA'),
 (872570, '23130', 'NY'),
 (872570, '133752', 'AZ'),
 (872570, '4210', 'MN'),
 (872570, '7463', 'GA'),
 (872570, '23130', 'NY'),
 (872570, '133752', 'AZ')]
```

Comment: Yes this works but the BranchesStates should be split at the corresponding position in BranchesNr when the element is zero, except for the first 0. So for the example I mention, BranchesStates should be split into 4 pieces: [:2], [2:4], [4:6], [6]. Does this make more sense? So from the first 0 to the second 0, from the second zero to the third zero, etc.

Comment: I believe the `indices` variable indicates when the splits should occur, but I'm still not sure on this logic. Can you please provide a more varied example?

Comment: So suppose there are two employers A and B who have one branch each: A1 and B1. So the data would look like this:
    `Individual (A,B) (A1,B1) (0,0)`
But I don't necessarily know which of the branches belongs to which employer, could be that A1 and B1 belong to A actually. So (0,0) indicates that the first branch belongs to the first employer and the second branch belongs to the second employer. If the value for BranchNr were (0,1) I would now that both branches belong to A. Is that clearer?